# How do I create modal input form corresponding to row of table from which modal is activated?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple bootsrtap table in which each row has a edit button. How do I open a modal corresponding to the row from which it was called?
(In react.js)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, I recommend you to use react-strap(https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/) which is simple and easy to use.

This link contains example for how to use bootstrap Modal.